# Check if record is first in the month

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to check if my added record was the first in the month. What am I doing wrong? Show me how to do it, please.

I trield like

```
DECLARE var_month number; IF (INSERTING OR DELETING OR UPDATING) AND var_month <= 1 THEN
```

but it didn't work

Here's my query code:

```
CREATE TABLE Client_Statistics
(
id number(20),
client_id number(20),
year number(4) check (year between 1900 and 9999),
month number(2) check (month between 1 and 12),
order_count varchar2(10),
order_sum number(10,2)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE cs_seq 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_record_with_sequence
AFTER 
INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE sel number;
csdate number;

BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR DELETING OR UPDATING
    THEN
    INSERT INTO Client_Statistics (id, client_id, year, month, order_count, order_sum)
    VALUES (cs_seq.nextval, cs_seq.nextval, 2019, 5, cs_seq.nextval, cs_seq.nextval);
    END IF;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into sel
    FROM Client_Statistics;
IF sel != NULL
THEN 
    INSERT INTO Client_Statistics (id, client_id, year, month, order_count, order_sum)
    VALUES (cs_seq.nextval, cs_seq.nextval,  2019, 5, cs_seq.nextval, cs_seq.nextval);
END IF;
END add_record_with_sequence;
```

I expect the trigger to work if my code in the first `IF` condition is met. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is never `NULL`, so - what you check:

```
if sel != null
```

is never met. Use

```
if sel > 0
```

instead

Comment: Even if `sel` *were* `NULL`, the `if` would still not do what the OP intends.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that :) But i meant the first condition. I have to write this condition, but I don't know how exactly to do it, sorry. I sure could use your help, guys.